# Can I use openFDA API for Drugs side effects?

Tags: api, openfda, drugs

Is there any way to get Drugs side effect for specific drug name like Paxil from openFDA API. I read the documentation but don't really understand

Answer (score 0):

I'm Violet with the openFDA team. To find side effect information, you'll want to look for the `adverse_reactions` field in the endpoint `drug/label`.

[An example /drug/label query for Paxil.](https://api.fda.gov/drug/label.json?search=openfda.brand_name:Paxil&limit=10)

For a full list of all reactions reported while a patient was taking the drug, you can check the endpoint `drug/event`, but please note that these reports are per incident and often reference multiple drugs, meaning the drug you're looking for may not be *causally* related to the reaction.

[A count of all reactions reported which include Paxil (check the url for the full query - it's complex.)](https://api.fda.gov/drug/event.json?search=patient.drug.openfda.brand_name:paxil&count=patient.reaction.reactionmeddrapt.exact)

Please remember that there's a lot of information included within these endpoints, but it's intended for research purposes and requires medical training to properly parse and relate to healthcare. Do not rely on openFDA to make decisions regarding medical care. Always speak to your health provider about the risks and benefits of FDA-regulated products.

Have a great day,

Violet